# 'flutter_web_plugins from sdk doesn't exist' error

Tags: dart, yaml

I am trying to add a video to a page in Flutter and am getting the following error:

```
'Because video_player >=2.0.0 depends on video_player_web ^2.0.0 which depends on flutter_web_plugins from sdk, video_player >=2.0.0 requires flutter_web_plugins from sdk.
```

So, because flutter_web_plugins from sdk doesn't exist (could not find package flutter_web_plugins in the Flutter SDK) and longcovidbase depends on video_player ^2.2.12, version solving failed.'

I've imported these into the main.dart file

```
'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';'
```

and this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: longcovidbase
description: For long covid sufferers.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  video_player: 2.7.1
  flutter_svg:
  google_fonts:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  video_player: ^2.2.12


flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      web: null # Exclude web support
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I solved it by updating Flutter. At first it didn't let me update it with the basic command, so I forced it.

```
flutter upgrade --force
```